# Issue with adding Scroll View with Autolayout

Tags: autolayout, scrollview, ios9, size-classes

I have followed many accepted answers and many tutorials to know the way to add scroll view with Auto Layout but none of them helped me. Thus, I am now posting that as a question.

The common thing I found in the answers and tutorial is that none of them used Navigation Bar and the content which they are showing can come within the bounds of the screen but we need to scroll when content can't come within the bounds of screen. I have shared the image along with this question and my question is how can I show this on Scroll view on iPhone 5 screen with the help of Auto Layout.

[image]

> I am working on an iPad Application and I have set the following constraints.

Please see them in an image below:

[image]

Comment: @EI Captain Please see the constraints in the edit of my question

Comment: No! That is out side of the scrollview as you can see that

Comment: @halfer Sometimes warnings may work rather down voting any question and without knowing the answer.

Comment: On average, comments don't work, in my opinion. I would estimate 99% of users who add urgent/ASAP begging to their questions - people who seem to think their questions are more important than others that came in on the same day - do not reply constructively (or at all) to such feedback.

Comment: Anyway, I recalled that I have edited this sort of thing from you before. I count 6 or 7 instances of urgent begging I've edited out, and you will have received an edit notification for each one. You are lucky to get away with just one downvote.

Comment: @halfer OK, I am agree on that you have sent me reminders for that and also comments won't work in order to get the urgent response. But you know many times I have places bounties on my questions and I never get a satisfactory answer. That is why I stopped doing that because users takes a chance if they can earn the points if I accept there answers and thus I receive many irrelevant answers. Do you also take a look on the Relevant answers or just look into the Comments? Moreover, let me know the way in which I can have the answer in a quicker way as sometime one is really in need answer ASAP.

Comment: @halfer And I welcome your down vote!

Comment: I appreciate that developers will frequently have urgent technical issues, and that they would like assistance from volunteers on a speedy basis. However, it is important to remember that it is _only_ urgent for the poster, and not for anyone else. Thus, it is not appropriate to ask for urgent treatment, since (a) this is essentially a request that the question should be prioritised over other people's questions, which is selfish; (b) it attempts to transfer pressure onto volunteers to spend more effort on questions than they have time for; (c) it is noise that needs editing out.

Comment: If you often find yourself needing urgent assistance on technical issues, there are websites dedicated to paid help (e.g. AirPair). Paying for help can make it much more likely that you get the help you need in the timescales required, and if your work is commercial then paying for that assistance should not be impossible.

Comment: @halfer As I said earlier, I welcome your down vote! I don't have any issue with that.

Comment: That doesn't answer my new points, but never mind...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this constraints...

**For topbar**

```
  pinned all 4 edges 
  and give height constraint
```

**For scrollview**

```
 pinned all 4 edges
```

**For View inside scrollview**

```
pinned all 4 edges
equal width to superview
and height constraint
```

Comment: Why I need height constraints of "View inside scrollview". It will fix the height and it may not work properly in landscape view

Comment: Here is the link of the image where you can see the constraints I set according to you. But when I am running the code, I can't see the View I have added over the ScrollView.-------------------
https://www.dropbox.com/s/yxhxc2l5cu8eb26/Screen%20Shot%202016-03-21%20at%202.22.08%20PM.png?dl=0-------------------

If you want I can send you my code as well so that you can run and see that thing by yourself.

Comment: Can you please share your email id?

Comment: Anything did you find? :-|

Comment: Let me check once and then I will let you know what I want to do

Comment: Have you deleted the file? I can't see your comment as well

Comment: Its not covering whole height of iPad
http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=46475776577028874280

That is why I was not fixing the height.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106894/discussion-between-ei-captain-and-developer).